# How to manage keyboard shortcuts apps priority in Linux

Tags: unity, keyboard, 22.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

Having multiple apps open may introduce some conflicts at commons keyboard shortcuts. In order to control the behavior, I'm looking for a way to define the priority of these shortcuts/hotkeys. A more concrete example of this conflict is:

Both program A and B are running, and both of them have an action for the shortcut `Ctrl+E` (1). But when I'm using the program `A` and press the shortcut (1), instead of acting the program `A` action, it's trigger the action of program `B`.

How can i control these type of behavior?

I am currently using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: You will have to be specific: the behavior you describe is not standard. Application specific shortcuts are *not* triggered if the application is not in focus.

Comment: The program `B` actually stays running in the background. I have found that it defines a *system-wide* shortcut for hotkey (1), and probably this explains the behavior. But I wonder if there isn't a system-driven solution so that I can configure this behavior without depending on the application config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Linux desktop, system-wide shortcut keys take precedence over shortcut keys defined by the application.

> But when I'm using the program A and press the shortcut (1), instead of acting the program A action, it's trigger the action of program B.

This can only be explained if Program B has set up a global shortcut key. If you do not want this, you have to configure Program B not to use that shortcut key. There is no system-level way to control this: this is set up through the application.

On a side note, this won't happen when you run Wayland with native Wayland applications (it will only happen between applications running on xwayland). Wayland still has not implemented any way for applications to listen to global shortcut keys.